# error in dql sql use COALESCE in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

hi i use dql and subquery in my query 
when compile my code return error please help me 
my code is

```
$subQb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery = $subQb->select('COUNT(v.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'v')
                ->where('v.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('v.createdate > :date')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery2 = $subQb2->select('l.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Limitviewday', 'l')
                ->where($subQb2->expr()->eq('s.limitviewday', 'l.id'))
                ->getDQL();


            $subQb3 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery3 = $subQb3->select('COUNT(i.id)')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Visitsite', 'i')
                ->where('i.site = s.id')
                ->Andwhere('i.createdate > :date2')
                ->Andwhere('i.ip = :ip')
                ->groupBy('i.ip')
                ->getDQL();

            $subQb4 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $subquery4 = $subQb4->select('ipl.quantity')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Iplimitview', 'ipl')
                ->where('s.iplimitview = ipl.id')
                ->getDQL();



            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $query = $qb->select('s')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Sites', 's')
                ->where('s.quantity > :one')
                ->Andwhere('s.status = :two')
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("($subquery)", "($subquery2)"))
                ->Andwhere($qb->expr()->lt("(SELECT COALESCE(($subquery3),0))", "($subquery4)"))
                ->setParameter('one', 1)
                ->setParameter('two', 1)
                ->setParameter('date', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
                ->setParameter('ip', $ip)
                ->setParameter('date2', $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'));
            $settlements = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

and dql string result is

```
SELECT s FROM AdminBundle:Sites s WHERE s.quantity > :one AND s.status = :two AND ((SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM AdminBundle:Visitsite v WHERE v.site = s.id AND v.createdate > :date) < (SELECT l.quantity FROM AdminBundle:Limitviewday l WHERE s.limitviewday = l.id)) AND ((SELECT COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM AdminBundle:Visitsite i WHERE i.site = s.id AND i.createdate > :date2 AND i.ip = :ip GROUP BY i.ip),0)) < (SELECT ipl.quantity FROM AdminBundle:Iplimitview ipl WHERE s.iplimitview = ipl.id))
```

but my result is

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 284: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

please help me

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to achieve with this monster?